# How to submit an app that uses an iOS6 feature?

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa-touch

I'm ready to submit my app to apple, however it says on the iOS Dev portal that xCode 4.5 cannot be used to submit apps yet, use the public release.
xCode 4.4 wont compile my project because I am using some of the new iOS 6 code.

It seems strange with iOS6 round the corner that I cannot submit this. Must I remove this and submit, then resubmit to support iOS6 when they allow it, or has anyone successfully submitted from xCode 4.5 beta 4?

Thanks

Comment: I dont think i've broken the NDA with what i've asked. It's public knowledge and was in the WWDC videos

Comment: The WWDC videos are restricted to those that have signed up for a developer account; they're not public.

Comment: It's not that big of a secret that iOS6 will be released (sooner or later)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't submit with 4.5. Taking your statement that what you're doing is an iOS 6 feature without further inspection, you wouldn't want to submit at present because nobody has iOS 6. Your app wouldn't work on anybody's device.

If you want to release an iOS 6 app, wait until people have iOS 6 devices. If you want to release before iOS 6, make sure you're iOS 5 compatible and — for now — just disable your iOS 6 code.

Comment: The reason I wanted to keep it in, is the app won't work correctly at all on anyone using iOS6 beta, but I guess they'll just have to expect it.

Comment: Obviously it's iOS 6 so we can't discuss it, but I'd dare imaging that adding `shouldRotateToOrientation` in addition to what you have may be the smart thing when you can release for 6. Historically it's quite common that they'll say 'iOS whatever is out in a week, you can start submitting now'.

Answer (score 1):

You can't submit an app that links against a non-released SDK. That's unfortunately just the way it is. It's because the APIs are not locked in and might change.

My suggestion is to keep your code that uses the new APIs and re-submit once the SDK has gone live. This happens before the actual iOS version has been released to the general public, by the way.